# Trocar imagem de botão via código

Tags: genexus

Uso Genexus Evolution 3 Gerador C# Win. Eu gostaria de trocar a imagem de um botão via código. Eu coloquei no evento start o seguinte código:

botao.Bitmap=LoadBitmap('\figuras\imagem2.jpg')

Mas não funcionou. o botão fica em branco, não carrega a imagem.
Eu tentei colocar caminho relativo pra pegar dentro de uma subpasta de aonde a aplicação está rodando.

Grato

Comment: Já experimentou tirar a primeira barra invertida? `´figuras\imagem2.jpg´`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insira a imagem do botão com View > Images, e depois use uma variável do tipo imagem.

Assim vc consegue carregar a o botão como imagem no evento Start da página

&Seletor.FromImage(SelRow)

Espero ter ajudado.